# partial ancestor fetches before deletion from the AppEngine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model, datastore

I'd like to delete a bunch of objects from the AppEngine datastore within a transaction:

```
def F():
  items_to_delete = []
  for item in db.Query().ancestor(...):
    if item.aaa ... item.bbb:
      items_to_delete.append(item)
  db.delete(items_to_delete)
db.run_in_transaction(F)
```

Is it possible to fetch only a few fields of the items (`aaa` and `bbb`)? Will such a fetch have a positive effect on performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to fetch only a few fields; i.e. you'll always be fetching the entire entity with all its fields (or just the entity keys). From the [App Engine GQL reference docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html):

```
The GQL syntax can be summarized as follows:   
    SELECT [* | __key__]
        [FROM <kind>]]
        [WHERE <condition> [AND <condition> ...]]
        [ORDER BY <property> [ASC | DESC] [, <property> [ASC | DESC] ...]]
        [LIMIT [<offset>,]<count>]
        [OFFSET <offset>]
```

and

> A GQL query returns zero or more entities or Keys of the requested kind. Every GQL query always begins with either `SELECT *` or `SELECT __key__`. (A GQL query cannot perform a SQL-like "join" query.) Tip: `SELECT __key__` queries are faster and cost less CPU than `SELECT *` queries.

Comment: So how do I fetch only the `__key__` in an `db.Query().ancestor(...)` query?

Comment: @pts Try `db.Query(keys_only=True).ancestor(...)`: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NDB tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dsx1hihmMXMJm8wIRu49tJR-KEng80o3wkg4Nlbqn-w/edit?hl=en&ndplr=1), written by Guido himself (*bow to ground and say "I'm not worthy" x 3* :). He uses AND OR in query and fetching a few fields with offset (that answers your question). Still experimental though, so use with caution until it is out of preview.